# Finding Numerator of a equation after separating Denominator

Tags: homogeneous-equation, rationalising-denominator

In this following equation, after separating Denominator (1+v) & (1-v) in right side, how do I calculate the Numerator will be exactly (3/2) & (1/2)?
[image: image 1]

Answer (score 0):

it is the partial fraction  decomposition of $$\frac{2+v}{1-v^2}$$ it is $$\frac{2+v}{1-v^2}=\frac{A}{1-v}+\frac{B}{1+v}$$